# GIF animation on canvas with frame control

Tags: javascript, canvas, gif

I have some frames within gif and i want to play them on canvas with collision detection.
Is there someway how to extract frames from gif with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that JavaScript has no simple way of controlling the current frame of an Animated GIF.

The long answer is that there are sort-of ways to do what you want with just JS, but they are very much convoluted hacks.

Example of hackish way: Create a canvas and don't add it to the DOM (so this won't be seen by anyone). In a fast loop (setTimeout), draw to this canvas constantly and collect snapshots. Compare the canvas ImageData to see if the frames have changed or not.

Comment: This should not work: `when a CanvasImageSource object represents an animated image in an HTMLOrSVGImageElement, the user agent must use the default image of the animation (the one that the format defines is to be used when animation is not supported or is disabled), or, if there is no such image, the first frame of the animation, when rendering the image for CanvasRenderingContext2D APIs` [html.spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage#image-sources-for-2d-rendering-contexts). My test confirm this behavior in FF