# Extract frames from gif using a light browser JS libary (like omggif)

Tags: javascript, typescript, frame, gif

I'd like to extract frames from a gif file in the browser. More specifically, given the url of a gif `gifUrl: string`, I'd like to download it and obtain it as an array of frames `imageList: ImageData[]`). I'll be using `putImageData` on them at various coordinates of a canvas. I'd also like the solution to be lightweight.

On [BundlePhobia](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=omggif@1.0.10), [omggif](https://www.npmjs.com/package/omggif) is 50ms-long to download via emerging-3G. All alternatives I've seen so far are more around 700ms. However, omggif only offers the basic low level interactions, and common recipes like getting the gif as an array of ImageData are missing.

The best documentation I've found for omggif so far are [omggif's types in the DefinitelyTyped project](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/omggif/index.d.ts).

There's also [movableink's example](https://github.com/movableink/omggif/blob/example-web/example_web/index.html) (awaiting in a PR since January 2019).

I use TypeScript and am thus interested in typed recipes if possible.

Related questions:

- [How to extract frames from an animated gif using javascript? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39309560/how-to-extract-frames-from-an-animated-gif-using-javascript)
- [GIF animation on canvas with frame control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12143157/gif-animation-on-canvas-with-frame-control)

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you do it:

```
import { GifReader } from 'omggif';

export const loadGifFrameList = async (
    gifUrl: string,
): Promise<ImageData[]> => {
    const response = await fetch(gifUrl);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    const intArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    const reader = new GifReader(intArray as Buffer);

    const info = reader.frameInfo(0);

    return new Array(reader.numFrames()).fill(0).map((_, k) => {
        const image = new ImageData(info.width, info.height);

        reader.decodeAndBlitFrameRGBA(k, image.data as any);

        return image;
    });
};
```

If you need transparency, you might want to use canvas, as they can then be interfaced with `ctx.drawImage(canvas, x, y)`:

```
import { GifReader } from 'omggif';

export const loadGifFrameList = async (
    gifUrl: string,
): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement[]> => {
    const response = await fetch(gifUrl);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    const intArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    const reader = new GifReader(intArray as Buffer);

    const info = reader.frameInfo(0);

    return new Array(reader.numFrames()).fill(0).map((_, k) => {
        const image = new ImageData(info.width, info.height);

        reader.decodeAndBlitFrameRGBA(k, image.data as any);

        let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        canvas.width = info.width;
        canvas.height = info.height;

        canvas.getContext('2d')!.putImageData(image, 0, 0);

        return canvas;
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks mate life saviour.

Comment: @mathieu-caroff rendering looks poor when using decodeAndBlitFrameRGBA at initialization. I believe it is intended to be used when rendering, and the 2nd argument should be previous contents from canvas, as seen in https://github.com/deanm/omggif/pull/31